# AWS Cognito: why is my user not found when responding to AdminRespondToAuthChallenge?

Tags: nestjs, amazon-cognito

**TL;DR** I'm able to create & confirm a user. When sending a response to `SMS_MFA_CODE` I am getting a 400 error that the user does not exist.

I am using [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) for an authentication provider. I've got everything *super* close to working.

Using Postman, I call `adminCreateUser` to register users. from that method, I'll get an email with my email & temporary password. When I attempt to sign in using the temporary password, I make a request to `adminRespondToAuthChallenge`:

```
// challenge.dto.ts

"challengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
"email": "example@email.com",
"newPassword": "MyNewPassw0rd!,
"authCode": null,
"session": "AYABeP_..."
```

```
// cognito-service.ts

try {
      await this.cognito
        .adminRespondToAuthChallenge({
          ChallengeName: challengeName,
          ClientId: this.userPool.getClientId(),
          UserPoolId: this.userPool.getUserPoolId(),
          ChallengeResponses: {
            USERNAME: email,
            NEW_PASSWORD: newPassword,
            SMS_MFA_CODE: authCode,
          },
          Session: session,
        })
        .promise();
} catch (err) {
    throw new BadRequestException(err.message);
}
```

Cognito returns a 200 response and I can see in the console that my user is confirmed. The next time I try to sign in, I get back a good MFA challenge:

```
{
    "ChallengeName": "SMS_MFA",
    "Session": "AYABeP_...",
    "ChallengeParameters": {
        "CODE_DELIVERY_DELIVERY_MEDIUM": "SMS",
        "CODE_DELIVERY_DESTINATION": "+******",
        "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "9551a8c2..."
    }
}
```

I'll take the session I get back along with the SMS code and send another request to the `adminRespondToAuthChallenge` method:

```
// challenge.dto.ts

"challengeName": "SMS_MFA_CODE",
"email": "example@email.com",
"newPassword": null,
"authCode": "123456,
"session": "AYABeP_..."
```

This is the response I'm getting back:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "User does not exist.",
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I've tried using different challenge params, but I think I'm using the right one, as the response back will tell me I'm missing `SMS_MFA_CODE`. I know my user exists since I can see that the user is confirmed. How can I confirm the MFA for my user?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your username(email) is not verified.
Make use of **UpdateUserAttributes** API with **email_verified** to **true**